# Why is this so slow

Tags: javascript, roblox

Im doing a google chrome extension and i was wondering why

```
window.onload = loadPage;
function loadPage() {
    document.getElementById('nav-robux-amount').innerHTML = '0';
    console.log("Robux are now in hide.");
}
```

is so slow and if it had any other alternative working faster.

Comment: Yes i was wondering if there is another way to execute this faster

Comment: Slow as in, it takes time to call this function ?

Comment: Yes its waiting until everything is loaded and is there an alternative that directly execute the script?

Comment: I have answered your query. Please accept if it works. Thanks!

Comment: as I understand you didn't use the event window.onload correctly.

Answer (score 5):

That is true, since you have used window.onload, it will get called only after entire page is loaded completely. If you don't need your function to wait for all the loadings, you can try giving a shot to DOMContentLoaded.

The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

Comment: Its kinda working but its going way to fast i see it a milisecond and then the normal amount show back. Is there a way to do like a "wait" or "sleep" ?

Comment: Do you have Jquery library in your code? or it is plain vanilla JS

Comment: Its Javascript so .js

Comment: Use Promises to make your JS version of sleep. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: It still just show for a milisecond then go back to the normal value

Comment: Sounds like there's some other JS running on the page which is replacing your replaced text.

Comment: Settings done by you ```document.getElementById('nav-robux-amount').innerHTML = '0';``` is getting modified it seems. The value persists when you use window.onload right? but the problem is it is slower

Comment: window.onload work but its slow and i want it directly. But now it look like something else is editing my robux value

Comment: This is the problem with Chrome extensions. You're trying to run code on a page that is likely using a fair amount of JS. You'll need to debug the page and figure out what is causing the value to be updated and somehow update it afterwards.

Comment: Ok i'll try to do that

Comment: Correct @Skully. You need to find out what is changing this value. if you control it, then above DOMContentLoaded will work

Comment: Ill try to do something like once ('nav-robux-amount') is loaded it edit